# Share Clipboard Between Ubuntu and Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, clipboard

I am trying to copy paste text between Windows Remote Desktop and Linux Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 with Mate Desktop.

I have seen several posts that mention killing the rdpclip.exe process (on Windows) and restarting it. I can only imagine this pertains to an old version since rdpclip.exe isn't even running and I can copy paste between Windows machines just fine. However to test the idea, I started the rdpclip.exe program but this did not have any effect.

I also made sure that the clipboard is checked for my remote desktop connection.

In case it's relevant, I setup remote desktop by first installing the Mate 2D Desktop and then installing XRDP.

I am using Windows 8.1 64-bit to remote into the machine.

Comment: Kudos to you for manually trying to set this kind of thing up. I don't know if it's an option for what you're trying to accomplish but I've always used a sweet program called Synergy.

http://synergy-project.org/?ab1&utm_expid=35973112-1.uprIMMHGRqWNzAJBWQ_uog.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: Synergy looks like a cool product! If I had an extra monitor to spare for my server, I would shoot for it. The Windows Remote Desktop took awhile to figure out as far as connecting to Ubuntu but it works really well other than the fact that I can't copy paste text back and forth which really slows me down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try WinSCP and create a ssh connection to the Linux machine. You can also share a folder on either the Linux or Windows machine and give them both access.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem and I couldn't solve it. So, that's not exactly an answer to the problem in question, but I used [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) to be able to share text between servers.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Sorry, but using pastebin.com is a way to circumvent the problem. So I'm not just stating I had the same problem. I'll leave the answer as it may help other people.